# Hybrid cloud access controls

Tags: authentication, access-control, cloud-computing

In a hybrid cloud setup, where we have a cloud component which writes data into an on premise component, is it necessary to have separate access controls between the cloud and on premise?

Our current setup is the user logs in with the same credentials that are stored on premise (using LDAP, which I think is okay, we wouldn't want users to have two separate credentials for each).

The only concern I can think of is that all actions in the cloud are not logged as such. Currently if the user does the same action on the cloud or on premise the audit trail doesn't specify the difference (as it is the same user). I assume this is a risk that would need to be addressed? And would there be any other risks with this approach?